# How to make the horizontal scroll bar permanently visible?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this piece of code in order to display an horizontal scroll bar along a container of elements. The issue is that the bar is evident only when I put the cursor above the element. If the cursor is not put on the container with the elements, the bar is not evident, therefore the user may not be aware he has to scroll. Any idea about how to modify it in order to make the bar permanently visible?

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide example HTML. It's difficult to debug in the dark. See [ask].

Comment: I think this is only configurable by the user's OS? Just make sure to use `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: Also, this is easily done with CSS.

Comment: I expect this to be a OS/browser implementation problem, that might be solvable with some css, but to make it easier to debug for us, try to make a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow-x: scroll;` for that element in a CSS rule to permanently display a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I'm sure you realize that this answer would represent a manifold duplicate on SO.

Comment: @evolutionxbox nvm, to few context in the comment. Came in after the edit on the answer. We might as well delete the comments regarding orientation

Comment: I edited the answer, @evolutionxbox seems right at least in regard to the question *title*

Comment: @Johannes yes, agreed.

Comment: @Johannes, it is not working. The bar is not visible in the standard template. It becomes visible only when I start scrolling. A standard user may be unaware it has to scroll.

Comment: @Angy Could it be that this only happens on a certain device or browser, for example on a smartphone or tablet?

Comment: @Johannes, I tried on both Safari and Chrome on PC. The scroll bar is present, but invisible. It becomes visible only when I start scrolling.

Comment: @Angy do you use a mac?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes

Comment: Then I would recommend changing the system preference to “always” https://www.nytimes.com/2017/02/02/technology/personaltech/solving-the-case-of-the-disappearing-scroll-bars.html