# Is there a way to make horizontal scrollbar permanent in Chrome Beta?

Tags: html

In the latest Chrome Beta Windows 10 (108.0.5359.40) horizontal scroll bars on elements with overflow and being auto-hidden after a second or so.

This makes it very difficult to navigate the UI as the only way to scroll horizontally is to hold shift + mousewheel.

The same issue doesn't seem to occur on Chromes latest full release.

Anyone know how to make the horizontal scrollbars permanent like they used to be?

How to reproduce: Add a  that extends past the width of the viewport. Place in a container div, and have that container set to overflow-x:auto. The scrollbar used to be permanent, but is now auto-hidden and doesn't reappear on mouseover.

Edit: overflow-x: scroll; doesn't work either in the latest beta.

Comment: that's for you
[how-to-make-the-horizontal-scroll-bar]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70201177/how-to-make-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-permanently-visible

Comment: @Nguyen_Satou Adding overflow-x: scroll; doesn't work in the latest beta. The bar still disappears after a second, and doesn't even reappear if I start scroll via shift + mwheel.